# DC.JC checkbox to shift groups and re renderALL

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

Im trying to make more dynamic a  barchart adding a bottom that change a the group of the chart in one group y group() and in the other .group().reduceSum().
This is the HTML

```
    <label  class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" id="shift" onclick=" shift();">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
```

This is the function

```
  if (document.getElementById("shift").checked == true) {
      
      dc.renderAll();
    } else {
      
      dc.renderAll();
    }
  }
```

And this is the index.js

```
d3.csv('data2.csv').then(data =>{
    data.forEach(d => {
      d.indisp = +d.indisp  ;
    });
    var ndx = crossfilter(data);
    var all       = ndx.groupAll();
    var catdim    = ndx.dimension(function (d) {return d['cat'];})
    
    var catGroup1    = catdim.group();

    var catGroup    = catdim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.indisp;});

   catChart
      .dimension(catdim)
      .group(catGroup)
```

The problem I have is that I don’t know where write the function that validate if the checkbox is checked or not and shift btw both catGroup and catGroup1 and renderall again.

Comment: I don't recognize the language with the square brackets - is that something server-side?  I would usually use `d3.select('#shift').on('click', () => { .... })` to detect the checkbox changing and change the group and redraw the chart there. (Redraw to animate; render to replace without animation.)

Comment: Happy to spell this out in an answer if it's helpful. I guess I'm not entirely clear what the question is, since IIUC the square-bracket code is supposed to do what you want (except that it needs to set the group).

Comment: I corrected my post... I think that I wrote the brackets trying to set the code format.

Comment: I think you just need to listen for the click? I showed the D3 way in my first comment, does that work?